# how to set title below a graph in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, title

example:

```
set title "title"
plot x
```

This will draw a graph with a title on the top. I want to move the title under the graph. What should I do?
More, how about the same problem in multiplot. I want to move the titles for every small graph s under each graph.
NOTE that the title is not the title in a plot which will be placed in the keys.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The advantage of using `set title` is, that some vertical space is automatically reserved for it. This works only when placing the title above the graph.

You can place it below the graph only by specifying an `offset`. But in this case you must adapt both the offset manually and also the bottom margin:

Consider the following example:

```
set multiplot layout 1,3

set title "title"
plot x

set title "positive offset" offset 0,1
plot x

set title "negative offset" offset 0,-2
plot x

unset multiplot
```

[image]

As soon as you have a too large negative offset, the top margin is reset as if you would have not title, but the bottom margin remains unchanged.

So you must set a label manually below the plots and adapt the bottom margin accordingly:

```
set multiplot layout 1,3

set xlabel "xlabel"
set label 11 center at graph 0.5,char 1 "first title" font ",14"
set bmargin 5
plot x

set label 11 "second title"
plot x

set label 11 "third title"
plot x

unset multiplot
```

[image]

In any case you need manual intervention and tweaking of the margins.